# Laravel Notification Passing Data

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass a relationship object through a notification in laravel. I have Practices, which can have many Doctors, and Doctors which can belong only to one Practice. They are connected via a foreign_id field on the Doctors table as `practice_id`. When someone creates a doctor, they typically create the practice at the same time. However, they also have the potential to select an existing practice via a select form.

When someone creates a new practice, I can pass `$doctor` and `$practice` through perfectly to the notification. But when they choose an existing practice, I can't seem to call the existing `$practice` to pass through. Here is my code:

**NewDoctor notification**

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject('MedReps Doctor Registration')
    ->line('Hello,')
    ->line('A new doctor has been registered:')
    ->line(' ')
    ->line($this->practice->name)
    ->line($this->practice->address)
    ->line(
        $this->practice->city
        . ', '
        . $this->practice->state
        . '  '
        . $this->practice->zip
    )
    ->line('Phone: ' . $this->practice->phone)
    ->line('Fax: ' . $this->practice->fax)
    ->line('Contact: ' . $this->practice->contact)
    ->line('Email: ' . $this->practice->email)
    ->line(' ')
    ->line(
        $this->doctor->first_name
        . ' '
        . $this->doctor->last_name
        . ', '
        . $this->doctor->type
    )
    ->line('NPI: ' . $this->doctor->npi)
    ->line('License: ' . $this->doctor->license)
    ->line($dea_line);
```

**DoctorController**

```
// If the practice already exists
if ($request->create_doctor_practice_type == 'existing') {
    $doctor = new Doctor();
    $doctor->practice_id = $request->practice;
    ... data ...
    $doctor->save();

    // Get Practice information for notification
    $practice = Practice::select('id')
        ->where('id', $request->practice)
        ->first();

    // Send notification
    Notification::route('mail', 'jeremy@medrepsrx.com')
        ->notify(new NewDoctor($doctor, $practice));

// Create a new practice
} else {
    $practice = new Practice();
    ... data ...
    $practice->save();

    $doctor = new Doctor();
    ... data ...
    $doctor->save();

    // Send notification
    Notification::route('mail', 'jeremy@medrepsrx.com')
        ->notify(new NewDoctor($doctor, $practice));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$practice = Practice::select('id') ->where('id', $request->practice) ->first();
```

To

```
$practice = Practice::find($request->practice);
```

When you create a new practice you send the whole practice object to your notification but when it already exists you're just sending the id.